# How can i get json data from a POST form containing file type input

Tags: c#, jquery

HTML

```
<form id="ajaxForm" action="/uploadHandler.ashx" method="post">
    <label for="Name">File name</label><input type="text" id="Name" />
    <label for="someData">Email</label><input type="text" id="Email" />
    <label for="file">Image</label><input name="uploadFile" id="fileName" />
</form>
```

AJAX: I have a generic handler that is receiving data from ajax POST call passing json-data and upload-file. like:

```
//        type: 'POST',
//        url: '/myHandler.ashx', 
//        data: '{"key":"val"}'
```

HANDLER: on the generic handler i want to get the post json data and stream the uploaded file. This is how i usually get POST json-data:

```
    var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonString = String.Empty;
    context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
    {
        jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    var uploader = jsSerializer.Deserialize<Uploader>(jsonString);

    //  the Uploader class looks like this
    public class Uploader{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

the problem here is that the `context.Request.InputStream` also contains uploaded file and cause the `jsSerializer.Deserialize` method to fail

What is the best way to extcat json data, if POST also contain file strem?

And the reason i am using POST method, besides being standard, is that i am also streaming the uploaded file using `System.Web.HttpFileCollection`, but that is working fine.

Comment: i don't understand everything on what you're trying to do, but your form should have the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute at least

Comment: Why use json here ? Why you don't just use request.Form values to read what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Ajax Code to :

```
//        type: 'POST',
//        url: '/myHandler.ashx', 
//        data: JSON.stringify({"key":"val"}),
//        dataType: "json" ,
//        contentType: "application/json"
```